# HTML from jsoup request different from that of source code viewed in chrome

Tags: java, html, google-chrome, jsoup

The HTML code from a simple jsoup post request to an IMDb page is vastly different from that of the HTML that is shown in chrome when clicking on view source.   I am curious as why exactly that is.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the page is different for different browser header, try to use an Chrome Header for the Jsoup request